# how to use the slug values of url in the template in django

Tags: django

```
 var params = {
            year: escape(year.val()),
            month: escape(month.val()),
            day:  escape(day.val()),
         };

  $(window.location).attr('href', getUrlSlug()+'enquiry/thanks/?year='+params.year+'&month='+params.month+'&day='+params.day);
```

Now in my teplate url its displaying as:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/venues/adc-dfds-hds-kdfdf-fd-dfd/enquiry/thanks/?year=2012&month=9&day=13
```

Now i want use the date in my template as follows

```
<p>Your chosen date is {{params.year}},{{params.month}},{{params.day}}</p>
```

i am not sure of syntax any help please...

Comment: Is `params` javascript variable or python variable in view?

Comment: You cannot really use JS variable in django template of same page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To dispaly the above values in a **template** I just used the below code....

```
{{request.GET.year}},{{request.GET.month}},{{request.GET.day}}
```

if to use the same in a **view** we need to use

```
request.GET.get('year')
request.GET.get('month')
request.GET.get('day')
```